# Why there is no close animation for windows in Gnome 3.8

Tags: 13.04, gnome, animations

Recently I installed Gnome Ubuntu 13.04 on my XPS 13. Everything works just fine instead there is no close windows animation like those in unity or kde. Is that a problem of hardware compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

There is no close animation in Gnome 3.8. Gnome is less flashy than KDE or Unity, and unfortunately at the moment I do not know if it is possible to add animations other than re-coding the window manager. If you want to customize your DE, the usual suggestion is to use KDE.